# Jquery .style is undefined

Tags: jquery, styles, undefined

I have a lot of tables in my page. Some tables have Width property defined inline -

```
style="width:100%; ..."
```

I need to get all such tables.
I tried

```
$('.Forum_Container table').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.style != undefined) {
        if ($this.style.width == '100%') {
            ...
        }
    } else {
        ...
    }
});
```

but $this.style is always undefined. What can cause this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `$(this)` you're creating a jQuery object that contains a reference to that DOM element. The `style` property is a property of the DOM element itself, not the jQuery object, so trying to access it won't work (because it *is* undefined).

Either use `this` (the actual DOM node) directly - i.e. `this.style.width` - or use the functions provided by jQuery to access the information you need.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery has `.css()` to get element style properties:

```
if ($this.css("width") == '100%') {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

If for some reason you want the raw style, you can grab it from the DOM element itself, not the jQuery object wrapping it:

```
if (this.style != undefined) {
    if (this.style.width == '100%') {
        ...
    }
} else {
    ...
}
```

The `this` will give you the "raw" element.

Answer (score 3):

`$this.prop('style').width` will work without using the raw element.

I was trying to determine if a margin was set to "auto" in earlier javascript, and `$this.prop('style').margin` will return the raw margin value with the word "auto" in it, whereas `$this.css('margin')` returns the calculated value.

Answer (score 2):

"style" is not a jQuery method.

"attr" or "prop" is what you are after

Answer (score 1):

You're checking for the `style` property of a **jQuery object**, not a DOM element. You need to convert the jQuery object into a DOM element as follows:

```
$('.Forum_Container table').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        this_style = this.style;
    if (this_style != undefined) {
        if (this_style.width == '100%') {
            ...
        }
    } else {
        ...
    }
});
```

Alternatively, if you're using jQuery, why not use the [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method?

Comment: Doing `$this[0].style` is the same as doing `this.style`, but without the pointless call to the `jQuery()` function.

Comment: Thank you, an oversight on my part. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `css()` function:

```
$this.css('width')
```

And in your `if` statement:

```
$this.hasAttr('style')
```